# Problem with react page printing for quotation or invoicing with fixed header and footer and custom page numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, printing

React page print with page number eg: (1 of 2)  with fixed header and footer what is the best approach to use? Or method to use in react js
For invoice/quotation purpose

React page print with page number eg: (1 of 2)  with fixed header and footer what is the best approach to use? Or method to use in react js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.